# Merging data from duplicate MySQL databases

Tags: mysql, merge

How should I go about merging data from 2 MySQL databases that have the same table structures?

The issue is that they have foreign keys, so merging them as is would result in 2 different pieces of data having the same Primary Key, and being linked to something they should not be linked to.

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

Comment: I'm afraid there are no easy solutions for this problem. Primary keys have to be unique - this leaves basically two options: merge the data and overwrite non-identical values or generate new ids and have duplicates in your database. I think it depends on your application domain - what data is stored in your database? Are duplicates acceptable? From my experience, merging is hard: you'll probably merge data which doesn't belong together and create erroneous data. Another idea would be to mark the duplicates and create an extra table / relation for that.

Comment: @ventiseis The data is hard drive serial numbers, file system names, and individual filenames. Unfortunately we cannot have duplicates as we have to relate files to their respected file systems, and those file systems to their respected hard drive serial numbers. Thank you for your input, we will likely use a new table, or remove the need to merge any data.